# Automated appending of csv files in linux with timestamp and id

Tags: linux, csv, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to append data from `File1` to `File2` (both csvs) in ubuntu Linux.

The data is to be appended every minute added with a timestamp and an auto-increasing id number (to be used as pk in a mysql db).

I have set up a crontab job:

```
* * * * * cat File1>>File2
```

It works perfectly, however i am a bit stuck with adding the two new columns to File2 that are to be auto populated.

I am a bit of a novice at linux and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you provide input and output examples?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please give a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Comment: Does File1 have more than one line? I assume so. So what you're asking is how to prepend something to every line in a text file?

Comment: The input will be (A, B, C, D) and output will look like (1, A, B, C, D, {timestamp}). Now each minute File one will have about 10 new records, and we will append these 10 into File 2. The id will be autoincreasing